# Как изменить имя команды в tcl?

Tags: tcl

Например, вместо `for` хочу писать `аа`. Попробовала так

```
proc aa {a b c d} {
    for {$a} {$b} {$c} {$d}
} 

aa {set k 0} {$k<5} {incr k} {puts $k}
```

но не получилось.

Comment: Вместо метки `script` укажите язык программирования.

Comment: попробовала укозать tcl но не было такой метки , а новую создать не позволенo

Comment: Это он https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl ?

Comment: да это он , я в вопросе тоже написала имя языка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте передать аргументы команде `for` напрямую, без дополнительных фигурных скобок вокруг аргументов:

```
$ tclsh
% proc aa {a b c d} { for $a $b $c $d }
% aa {set k 0} {$k<5} {incr k} {puts $k}
0
1
2
3
4
%
% # проверка
% for {set k 0} {$k<5} {incr k} {puts $k}
0
1
2
3
4
%
```

Comment: получилось, спосибо большое)))

Comment: если ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).